# how to post xml to the webservice and get a result using worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to worklight and using http adapter for posting xml to webservices so that i can get the result.But I am not able to do that it is giving some error. My code is in adapter.js

```
function getStories(interest) {
    path = getPath(interest);

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : path
        parameters : '<HOME><REQUEST><USERID>701692</USERID><SECURE_KEY>B6F86B1B11E9EAFC</SECURE_KEY><EMPLOYEE_ID>000000000000035B</REQUEST></HOME>'
    };


    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

It is giving output like this

> {    "errors": [
>         "Premature end of file.",
>         "Failed to parse the payload from backend (procedure: HttpRequest)"    ],    "info": [    ],    "isSuccessful": false,
>   "responseHeaders": {
>         "Cache-Control": "private",
>         "Content-Length": "0",
>         "Date": "Mon, 15 Oct 2012 10:29:01 GMT",
>         "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/6.0",
>         "X-AspNet-Version": "2.0.50727",
>         "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET"    },    "statusCode": 200,    "statusReason": "OK",    "warnings": [    ] }

I want to have this code (given below ) to be implemented in worklight , how can i do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<form name="f1" id="fi" action="http://mydoman.aspx" method="post">
<input TYPE="hidden" name="xml" value="<HOME><REQUEST><USERID>701692</USERID><SECURE_KEY>B6F86B1B11E9EAFC17F5844EE9B16669</SECURE_KEY></REQUEST></HOME>"/>

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>


</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a step, you are trying to send an XML to your backend.
Please read Module 5.3 - Using HTTP Adapters with SOAP Services at: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/index.html

The answer to your question is:

```
var request = <HOME><REQUEST><USERID>701692</USERID><SECURE_KEY>B6F86B1B11E9EAFC</SECURE_KEY><EMPLOYEE_ID>000000000000035B</EMPLOYEE_ID></REQUEST></HOME>;

function getStories(interest) {
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '',
        body : {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Comment: this is not working.....we can't pass request like this....I have given the html example in my question for ur refrence please read that and give me answer , how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

returnedContentType : 'xml' means that Worklight will try to parse the response it got from backend. Looking at the error message I can see "Content-Length": "0", which means that response body is empty, therefore it cannot be parsed to XML.
Try changing returnedContentType to 'plain'.

Comment: An error occurred while invoking procedure ICICI_CRM_ADAP/HttpRequest parameters: {
   "arr": [
      {
         "body": {
            "content": "<HOME><REQUEST><USERID>701692<\/USERID><\/REQUEST><\/HOME>",
            "contentType": "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"
         },
         "method": "post",
         "path": "Default.aspx",
         "returnedContentType": "plain"
      }
   ]
}
String index out of range: -1
Caused by: null

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = '<HOME><REQUEST><USERID>701692</USERID><SECURE_KEY>B6F86B1B11E9EAFC</SECURE_KEY><EMPLOYEE_ID>000000000000035B</EMPLOYEE_ID></REQUEST></HOME>';

function getStories(interest) {
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '',
        body : {
            content: request,
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```